# Checking if an association exists without catching an exception in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Would be possible to check if an association exists before issuing a query in Doctrine2? Example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Feature", inversedBy="product")
     */
    public $features;
}
```

I'd like to check (actually without issuing the query itself) it the association `product.features` exists.

**EDIT**: Out of curiosity i'm writing a service (an helper, really) to do some collection filtering based on GET paramters:

```
public function initialize($entityName, $key)
{
    // Defaults are empty values and empty collection
    $this->values     = array();
    $this->collection = new ArrayCollection();

    // If "$key" GET parameter is null or blank return this instance
    if(is_null($value = $this->request->get($key))
        || strlen(trim($value)) == 0) return $this;

    // Split the parameter value based on separator (typically a comma)
    $re = '/\s*' . $this->separator . '\s*/';

    // Return this instance if no values are found
    if(!($set = preg_split($re, $value, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY))) return $this;

    // Guess the repository fully qualified name and entity name
    $guesser    = $this->getManagementGuesser();
    $repoName   = $guesser->guessRepositoryName();
    $entityName = $guesser->guessEntityName();

    // Get the repository for the entity and create the builder
    $qb = $this->getRepository($repoName)->createQueryBuilder('e');

    // Check if a relation named $key exists and throw a LogicException
    $exists = $this->getEntitiesUtility()->checkRelation($entityName, $key);
    if(!$exists) throw new \LogicException("Relation named '$key' not found.");

    // Other stuff
}
```

The relavant part would be:

```
$this->getEntitiesUtility()->checkRelation($entityName, $relationName);
```

Comment: You mean if a given product has at least one associated feature record? You *have* to perform a query to do that.

Comment: @PeterBailey nope, i know i can inner join it. I'm talking about if product has actually a relation named "features".

Comment: Get the class metadata and loop through it to check if such relation has been defined in the entity. However I would go further to know why are you asking this because I suspect you're trying to solve so polymorphism problems or something like that, and there are better way to do if you are.

Comment: @BorisGuéry thank you for be interested in this. You are talking about simply checking (statically, it you understand what i mean) that `$features` actually exists? `$features` can exists of course without being a relation itself (could be merely a property). See my edits for the other question, and thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// $em being your EntityManager..

if ($em->getClassMetadata($className)->getAssociationMapping($fieldName))
{
   ....
}
```